# Replacing a certain number of characters after a match using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file `test.txt` that looks something like this:

`something=1something-else=234another-something=5678`

I would like to replace `something-else=234` with `something-else=***`, for example, but the only information I have is the "match" that is `something-else=` and that there are exactly THREE characters after the equals sign. Currently I have this command that replaces everything on the line after the match:

`sed -i -e 's/\(something-else=\).*/\1***/' test.txt`

Result: `something=1something-else=***`

How can I adapt it to only replace three characters instead of the entire rest of the line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for

```
sed -i -e 's/\(something-else=\).\{3\}/\1***/' test.txt
```

or, equivalently,

```
sed -i -e 's/\(something-else=\).../\1***/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I adapt it to only replace three characters instead of the entire rest of the line?

You can use:

```
sed 's/\(something-else=\).../\1***/' file

something=1something-else=***another-something=5678
```

Here `...` will match exactly 3 characters after `something-else=`.

You can also use a numbered in quantifier:

```
sed -E 's/(something-else=).{3}/\1***/' file
```